# Placement of ALSO in a sentence

Tags: adverbs, too-also

> 1. She found her bag and money **also**.
> 2. She found her bag and **also** money.

Which is correct? My grammar book is saying sentence 2 is correct, as “ALSO” shouldn’t come at the end of the sentence. Why so?

Answer (score 1):

*Both* of the sentences are grammatical.

The only difference is a matter of style, and which is more common than the other.

If you can end a sentence with *too* (and you can), you can also end a sentence with *also*.

- ✔ I like it **too**.
- ✔ I like coffee, and tea **too**.
- ✔ I like it **also**.
- ✔ I like coffee, and tea **also**.

In my examples, I've also added a comma before the second item in both cases. This makes it appear more natural.

- ✔ She found her bag, and money **too**.
- ✔ She found her bag, and money **also**.

I would say that ending the sentence with *too* seems more natural, but that doesn't mean that ending it with *also* is actually wrong.

---

From an answer to ["Is it grammatical to finish a sentence with 'also'?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/93012/291924) by Colin Fine at English Language and Usage:

> It's perfectly grammatical, and can be substituted by other words and phrases *too* and *as well*.
>
> I don't use also there myself, as it sounds rather American to me, but I accept it.

---

Some people don't put *also* at the end of sentences, and some style guides advise against doing so. But that's a matter of style rather than grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t tell you why, but as a native speaker the second sounds natural and the first sounds wrong.

“I’m going to the store and also the pharmacy” 
“She likes to swim and also ride her bike”

It seems like also needs to come before the second thing you’re taking about.

Answer (score 0):

They have different meanings in the end. In the first sentence the bag and money were lost together and are now found. In the second sentence she found her bag, as well as some money though it is not clear it was hers in the first place. By interjecting ‘also’ before ‘money’, it cancelled the possessive pronoun ‘her’ from being distributed to the ‘money’, along with the ‘her bag’.

Answer (score -1):

She also found her money along with her bag.